# XML to JavaBean

Tags: java, xml

The XML file is following:

```
<AuthnRequest xmlns="A" ID="B">
    <Issuer xmlns="A">SOMETHING</Issuer>
    <NameIDPolicy Format="B" AllowCreate="true"/>
</AuthnRequest>
```

So how to transform this file with many attributes to a Javabean?

I tired this like this but didn't work

```
@XmlRootElement(name="AuthnRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserAuthn {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String xmlns;
    @XmlAttribute   
    private String ID;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String Version;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String IssueInstant;
    @XmlElement
    private List<Issuer> Issuers;
    @XmlElement
    private List<NameIDPolicy> NameIDPolicys;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Class Issuer

```
private String xmlns;

@XmlAttribute
public String getXmlns() {
    return xmlns;
}

public void setXmlns(String xmlns) {
    this.xmlns = xmlns;
}
```

Class NameIDPolicy is the same :

```
private String Format;
private String AllowCreate;

@XmlAttribute(name="AllowCreate")
public String getFormat() {
    return Format;
}

public void setFormat(String format) {
    Format = format;
}
@XmlAttribute(name="Format")
public String getAllowCreate() {
    return AllowCreate;
}

public void setAllowCreate(String allowCreate) {
    AllowCreate = allowCreate;
}
```

And the error is

```
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"A", local:"AuthnRequest"). 
Expected elements are <{}AuthnRequest>] with root cause
```

Comment: Get (or write) an XSD and use a tool such as [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/).

Comment: @sp00m Hi. Could you have a look at my job already done?

Comment: `xmlns` is not an attribute, it's a namespace declaration.  You need to set up your JAXB annotations to use the right namespace, which you'd usually do with a package-level annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the `<AuthnRequest>` element is in a namespace `A`, and your annotations don't specify that namespace. That namespace is specified in the special `xmlns` attribute, which you're trying to map with `@XmlAttribute`

Try this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="AuthnRequest", namespace="A")
```

and remove the `@XmlAttribute` for `xmlns`.

You may also have to specify `namespace` for some of the `@XmlElement`-annotated fields in `UserAuthn`, such as

```
@XmlElement(name="Issuer", namespace="A")
private List<Issuer> Issuers;
```